# Fieldset disappears in quirks mode

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a form which is split into multiple fieldsets which works fine in almost all browsers.  When viewing in quirks mode in IE however, 3 of the 5 fieldsets are not visible.  The html is rendered but they are not displayed.  The offending outrage can be found here: http://www.pocketpayday.co.uk/apply-online.aspx.  I can't  see anything different between the sections that are displayed and those that aren't?

Comment: Why don't you just write the page in a standard-compliant way then?

Comment: If I could figure  out what is triggering quirks mode that would also solve my issue

Comment: Ah right, the way I read the question, it sounded like you were deliberately triggering quirks mode. My mistake.

Comment: quirks mode is usually triggered when you do not supply a doctype.  Just add one and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the top of your code it should sort it out

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Then after it should work